# Can CoreData return unique entity attributes?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, predicates

Lets say I have an entity with an attribute called animalType.
Within core data I have 10,000 of these entities and there are an unknown amount of different animal types, Eg. dog, cat, bird, etc.
Can I tell core data to fetch each animal type and return an array similar to:

```
@[Dog, Cat, Bird, Fish, ...]
```

I don't want to fetch an array of entities I just want a unique list of `animalTypes`.
No `animalType` should be repeated.

Comment: You're welcome! See the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for tips on formatting and question style :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll want `NSFetchRequest`'s `setReturnsDistinctResults:` method, combined with `setPropertiesToFetch:` and `setResultType: NSDictionaryResultType`. Basically, the fetch will return an array of dictionaries, and those dictionaries will in turn contain key-value pairs corresponding to the specific properties you fetch-- in your case, each dictionary having one key, `animalType`, and a distinct value for that key. Converting that into an array like the one you describe would be straightforward.

Comment: This looks great! I'll give this a go and be back to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Animal"];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"animalType"];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext 
                         executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

NSArray *result = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"animalType"];

// @[@"Dog", @"Cat", @"Fish" ...]
```

Comment: This is also an outstanding answer! Thank you!